# How to turn off the Bicycling layer after it gets turned on by the DirectionsRenderer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In [the documentation on Layers in the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers), the following is stated:

> The Bicycling layer object renders a layer of bike paths and/or bicycle-specific overlays into a common layer. This layer is returned by default within the DirectionsRenderer when requesting directions of travel mode BICYCLING.

How would one turn off this Bicycling Layer after it got turned on by the DirectionsRenderer? I do want to show the biking route, but don't want all the green lines of the Bicycling Layer mess up the clarity of the map.

Is there a way to 'get' the current Bicycling Layer, and turn it off/unbind it from the map that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just disable the display of the bicyclingLayer by the DirectionsRenerer, per the [documentation for the DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) you can suppress the BicycleLayer by using the `suppressBicyclingLayer` option in the DirectionsRendererOptions:

> **suppressBicyclingLayer** | Type:  boolean | Suppress the rendering of the BicyclingLayer when bicycling directions are requested.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8rp9y2zq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressBicyclingLayer: true
  });
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var onChangeHandler = function() {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
    travelMode: 'BICYCLING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <b>Start: </b>
  <input id="start" value="New York, NY" />
  <br><b>End: </b>
  <input id="end" value="Newark, NJ" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `layer.setMap(null)`.

Something like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap')
var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
document.getElementById("showBikeLayer").addEventListener("click", function(){
  bikeLayer.setMap(map);
});
document.getElementById("hideBikeLayer").addEventListener("click", function(){
  bikeLayer.setMap(null);
});
```