# Google map black lines

Tags: android, google-maps

I noticed that Google Maps has added some black lines to the view on Google Maps. I'd like to know what they are supposed to indicate and how to turn off these black lines. see below image for reference how can I remove these black lines.

[image: screenshot of google maps showing black lines]

Comment: can you be more specific? Can you attach any image?

Comment: The black lines appear when you set map details to show bicycling paths in the Google Maps app. I suspect this has something to do with the map type you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off the Bicycling layer after it gets turned on by the DirectionsRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699388/how-to-turn-off-the-bicycling-layer-after-it-gets-turned-on-by-the-directionsren)

Comment: There is no such lines are appearing currently as I checked it today.

Answer (score 2):

[They are the MRT lines of Singapore.](https://www.reddit.com/r/singapore/comments/967vqi/mrt_lines_are_all_black_colour_google_maps/) Apparently they appeared in other cities as well but in the right colors, I guess the MRT lines will get colored as well at some point.

Edit: They used to be colored, I just never noticed them. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: Yes it's colored ever since Google Maps was introduced, and up until few days ago, it's overlapped with black lines. Seems like another data set has been imported and overlapped the original colored MRT lines. Reported in maps app though, hopefully they would fix it asap. I stay in Singapore.

Answer (score 1):

seems like a bug to me, because these lines were in colors for years before yesterday, and it is not caused by whatever Bicycling layer either, because all of my friends encounter the same started at the same time.

It's funny that non of the users who replied this thread are living in Singapore, but still trying to answer this query, apparently those replies before mine are not true.

There are reports sent to Google Singapore for further investigation, so no worries, these MRT lines will be back to be colored accordingly in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I see this in Singapore zone in google maps app, but if you want to remove it, use custom styles for your app like:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
      try {
            boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mystyles));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
    }
```